# How do you do a multi-line text area in primeng?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, primeng

I think this should be a pretty quick question.

I have an html/primeng app in which I have an input of type text...

```
<span text-align="top">
  <input type="text" pInputText required maxlength="500" [(ngModel)]="mymodel"
        [style]="{width: '500px', height: '500px'}">
      
</span>
```

As you can see from the height: '500px' specification I would like for this to be a large text area into which the user can type in lots of text.

The height: '500px' specification does make the input area taller - but it still behaves like a single-line input, with the text smack in the center and with no wrapping...

Any suggestions?  Thanks much.

[image]

Comment: `<input />` is for a single-line input. You're looking for `<textarea>` and the `col` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use textarea instead of the input field
Like this :

```
<textarea id="que1" name="Question" rows="4" cols="50">
```